# Could not read search indexes

Tags: python, google-chrome, google-app-engine, flags, gae-python27

Hello I have this issue when running google app engine with python (working on Udacity courses)

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine>dev_appserver.py D:\gcloud\hw_templates
INFO     2016-09-09 17:26:44,811 sdk_update_checker.py:229] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2016-09-09 17:26:45,924 sdk_update_checker.py:257] The SDK is up to date.
WARNING  2016-09-09 17:26:46,247 simple_search_stub.py:1146] Could not read search indexes from c:\users\cheun\appdata\local\temp\appengine.udacity-cs253\search_indexes
INFO     2016-09-09 17:26:46,259 api_server.py:205] Starting API server at: http://localhost:64506
INFO     2016-09-09 17:26:46,266 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2016-09-09 17:26:46,272 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
```

it seems that It can't find the search indexes file, I have read that he might because of some parameter in chrome://flags - BuiltInDnsClient set to Disabled,

but it seems this toogle parameter is not anymore in the flags... can you help on this please ?

thanks a lot guys!

Comment: I can't imagine why this would be related to a flag in Chrome.

Comment: is there an actual problem?

Comment: Currently I can load deploy my code locally, but a warning is never too good right ? I don't know yet what this warning prevents me from.. but If i can already get over it that would be nice !

Answer (score 1):

For posterity,

Try running your `Google Cloud SDK Shell` (or whichever program used) with `run as Administrator`.

At least that was how I fixed mine.